# AWS Connect cannot call lambda / save recording to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Connect and I tried to save recordings + trigger lambda in an incoming flow.

Here's the diagram:
[image]

However, I can't see any files in the bucket or even any logs in lambda. Is there something wrong in the diagram? I also enabled saving recording to s3 with the default bucket AWS Connect suggested. I can see the bucket but it's always empty.

Thanks!

## ****EDIT****

The logs of `/aws/connect/personal` is also empty

Answer (score 0):

To enable your recordings from the dashboard in the Set block pull Set logging behavior onto your contact flow and touch enable. The lambda follow the instructions laid out here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-lambda-functions.html. You need to be sure that you generate the permissions for Connect to access the lambda in your terminal utilizing aws-cli an example is given review the parameters that you need to change from the code provided.

Lastly be sure to save, and then save and publish and in a few minutes your changes should take effect.